# Load labels for classifying Histopathology images in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I want to work on classification task. The dataset set I am using is [here](https://warwick.ac.uk/fac/sci/dcs/research/tia/data/crchistolabelednucleihe/). The data consist of histology images and there are four classes. The class labels are given in form of coordinates. How to fit a model with such type of data and corresponding labels (given in form of coordinates) for classification task.

Comment: I'm assuming that the problem you are interested in is a multi-label classification problem. I don't have stable network and couldn't download the files to look into it myself, but the conventional, easy way of labeling is to use [one-hot encoded vectors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-hot). For instance, for each coordinate, you would assign a vector like `[0, 0, 1]`. The length of the vector depends on the number of classes or labels. For example, if there are 8 classes in total, you would only need a three-dimensional vector since 2^3 = 8.

Comment: there are total 100 images and for each image there are 4 different files. These four different files are basically the classes. Each file consists of coordinates of pixel belonging to that class. So you are basically saying that , I should assign vector to each coordinate in an image?